# How Can I Ensure Dragged Element Clone Retains Original's Width

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jQuery UI Draggable to drag a `<div>` whose width is calculated as part of the layout (`margin:auto;`).

When dragging that element using `helper:clone`, the clone also gets the `margin:auto;` style, but is no longer constrained by the original's container.

Result: The cloned `<div>` may have a different width than the original.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/ajpVS/1/

How can I cause the clone to retain the original's width?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to set the width and the margin on the cloned element based on the draggable object when it is dropped, using `$(ui.draggable).clone().css({ ... });`

Here's an updated fiddle for you, should be what you're looking for. It will also keep the width for the helper object as well. http://jsfiddle.net/ajpVS/2/

Answer (score 17):

Jon's answer is really good, but it doesn't work properly when you have child elements in the draggable. When that's the case, the `event.target` can represent your draggable's children, and you'd want to modify the draggable's `helper()` method something like:

```
$(".objectDrag").draggable({
  helper: function(e) {
    var original = $(e.target).hasClass("ui-draggable") ? $(e.target) :  $(e.target).closest(".ui-draggable");
    return original.clone().css({
      width: original.width() // or outerWidth*
    });                
  },
  ...
});
```

[Without this](http://jsfiddle.net/0qksz70t/1/), the helper would represent any child element clicked within the draggable (click the within the light blue region in the "Drag 1" box for example). [Adding the additional logic above](http://jsfiddle.net/0qksz70t/) ensures that the draggable element is used for the helper. Hope that helps for anyone in a similar situation!

---

* *Note*: You'll want to use [`outerWidth`](http://jsfiddle.net/0qksz70t/2/) if the original element has `box-sizing: border-box` applied (thanks to @jave.web for raising).

Comment: I would up-vote this, however I'm unsure where this code should be placed, specifically.  Does this go in the drag start event?

Comment: @cale_b you're testing my memory of jQuery UI! I'll update my answer to what I believe I was trying to fix!

Comment: I would suggest using `.outerWidth()` and `.outerHeight()` if simple `.width()`/`.height()` works badly for you :)

Comment: @jave.web good point, for reference the outer variants include padding and borders, and you'll need to use them if the original element has `box-sizing: border-box` applied (which is quickly becoming the standard). [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/0qksz70t/2/).

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is.. where you have:

```
<div style="width:50px">
```

it also needs to be included in the objectDrag class:

```
<div class="objectDrag" style="width:50px;margin:auto; color:white;border:black 1px solid; background-color:#00A">Drag me</div>
```

I hope thats what you meant!

EDIT:

Hi took another quick look
http://jsfiddle.net/He2KZ/1/

I used the width:inherit property to inherit the parents width no matter what size it is. Also I noticed removing the border fixed the problem. the dragable clone is 2px out and you have a border of 1px. This is kinda buggy from Jquery-ui IMO they should account for borders at least.

If you really want borders try using "outline" instead of "border". This does not add to the width of the div.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that.  In my real code, that column contains a bunch of stuff that is draggable.  Updated the fiddle to reflect that.  The point is that the thing being dragged does not implicitly know its size, but only gets the size as a result of the layout.

Comment: +1 The edit works.  Jon's answer gives me slightly more flexibility so accepted that one, but yours is very good as well.